# Python - UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 44: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using pandas on Python 3 Jupyter notebook, I got

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position
>   44: character maps to

error while trying to read a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "Test1": {
        "A": "攻撃を続ける",
        "B": "残り資源",
        "C": "残りの資源を得るため小隊を修理し戦闘を続けろ："
    },
    "Test2": {
        "D": "{x} 日目",
        "E": "CC レベル {x}",
        "F": "本当にこれから全てのデバイスでこの基地を使用しますか？",
        "G": "この{social_network}アカウントには2つの基地が存在してます。基地の数は一人のプレイヤーにつき一つに限定されています。基地を選択するか、キャンセルしてください。",
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

[See full error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xc6m.png)

```
import pandas as pd

json_df = pd.read_json('input.json')
json_df
```

EDIT: I have also tried reading the json with the JSON module, it still the same error.

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text *in the question itself*. Do *not post links to images of code!*

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the file? Have you tried specifying the `encoding` argument?

Comment: I updated the text. The image was to show the complete error message, am not sure why it is not displaying instead its shows as link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `.json` file is encoded as UTF-8. `pd.read_json` tries to decode it as CP1252. You need to make it decode it as UTF-8:

```
import pandas as pd

json_df = pd.read_json('input.json', encoding='UTF-8')
json_df
```

Comment: I have tried that, I got error >>> TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: I got TypeError above. These are the available Signature: pd.read_json(path_or_buf=None, orient=None, typ='frame', dtype=True, convert_axes=True, convert_dates=True, keep_default_dates=True, numpy=False, precise_float=False, date_unit=None)

Comment: @userPyGeo: try upgrading pandas

Comment: Great, it worked after upgrading Pandas version: 0.19.2

Answer (score 5):

In case if you are reading Text file and you get the error
"python-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x81-in-position"

Then do this:
Convert the text file to CSV.

```
data=open('c:/.../path/.../filename.csv',encoding='utf-8')
data=data.read().lower()
```