# Choropleth folium Map

Tags: python, unicode, geojson, folium

I am trying to make a choropleth using folium & geopandas in python. I do receive a Unicode error and can not fix it.

My data frame looks like this:

```
choropleth_df =
```

| zipcode | color_bin |
| --- | --- |
| 7557 | 1 |
| 3993 | 2 |
| 4879 | 3 |
| 9788 | 2 |

The shapefile I use is from [here](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/dossier/nederland-regionaal/geografische-data/gegevens-per-postcode). I converted this data to a geojson data file!

An example of the choropleth is found [here:](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Choropleth-maps)

The code I am using is:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=8)
geojson_path = r'C:\xxxxx\CBS-PC4-2020-v1\CBS_pc4_2020_v1.geojson'

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geojson_path,
    name="choropleth",
    data=choropleth_df,
    columns=["zipcode", "color_bin"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="YlGn",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="# per zipcode",
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

The error I receive is:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 140: character maps to

Nou I found out by reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570459/displaying-country-in-choropleth-map-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant) that the geojson file I created probably uses another unicode, but how can I found out which one it uses?

Thank you in advance.

I created a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import os

choropleth_dict  = {'PC4': [1233, 2879, 3881, 9287], 'color_bin': [3, 2, 3, 1]}
choropleth_df = pd.DataFrame(data= choropleth_dict)

def load_shapes(filename):
    gdf_zipcodes = gpd.read_file(filename)
    zipcodes = gdf_zipcodes[['PC4', 'geometry']]
    zipcodes_in_latlon = zipcodes.to_crs(epsg=4326)
    return zipcodes_in_latlon

shapes_filename = r'\path\CBS_pc4_2020_v1.shp' ## here I use the shapefile (from the link)
shapes = load_shapes(shapes_filename)


m = folium.Map(location=[52, 6], zoom_start=8)

folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data= shapes,
            data = choropleth_df,
            columns=['PC4', 'color_bin'],  
            fill_color='YlOrRd',
            nan_fill_color="White", #Use white color if there is no data available for the county
            fill_opacity=0.7,
            line_opacity=0.2,
            legend_name='## per zipcode ', #title of the legend
            highlight=True,
            line_color='black', 
            encoding = 'UTF-8').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save('per_zipcode.html')
print("Saved to file .html")
```

When using only the .shp file, I am not receiving an error, however, I only see a black map, not the choropleth. When using the geojson file the same happens.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share an _executable_ code snippet + _full_ error traceback + data sample (sanitized if necessary)…

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I edited my question; the unicode errror seems to be solved. However, the map still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the black fill is that the key argument that relates the user data to the geometry is not specified. Therefore, it is necessary to specify the zip code in the geojson property value with 'key_on'. Or you need to specify geo_data as geojson or `shapes.__geo_interface__`. I have changed some of your data because the zip code did not exist. Finally, you can check the encoding of the file by using `pip install chardet` library, for example.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import os

choropleth_dict  = {'PC4': [5151, 2585, 3881, 9287], 'color_bin': [3, 5, 3, 6]}
choropleth_df = pd.DataFrame(data= choropleth_dict)
choropleth_df['PC4'] = choropleth_df['PC4'].astype(str)

def load_shapes(filename):
    gdf_zipcodes = gpd.read_file(filename)
    zipcodes = gdf_zipcodes[['PC4', 'geometry']]
    zipcodes_in_latlon = zipcodes.to_crs(epsg=4326)
    return zipcodes_in_latlon

shapes_filename = r'./Paht/CBS_pc4_2020_v1.shp' 
shapes = load_shapes(shapes_filename)


m = folium.Map(location=[52, 6], zoom_start=8)

folium.Choropleth(
            geo_data=shapes,#.__geo_interface__,
            data=choropleth_df,
            columns=['PC4', 'color_bin'],
            key_on='feature.properties.PC4',
            fill_color='YlOrRd',
            nan_fill_color="White", 
            fill_opacity=0.9,
            line_opacity=0.2,
            legend_name='## per zipcode ', 
            highlight=True,
            line_color='black', 
            encoding = 'UTF-8').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
#m.save('per_zipcode.html')
print("Saved to file .html")
m
```

[image]